# android - switch case and its return value

Tags: java, android

For my new app I need to print numbers chosen from a switch case. My switch cases should randomly pick an image and after that, the if statement should check which one was chosen and then change the score. The problem I have is, that my if statements get errors, because of `Unreachable Code`.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView score;
    public int newscore;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);    
    }

        int Id() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int imag = rand.nextInt(4);
        switch (imag) {
         case 0:
             score.setText(newscore);
             return R.drawable.a;
         case 1:
             score.setText(newscore);
             return R.drawable.b;
         case 2:
             score.setText(newscore);
             return R.drawable.c;
         default:
            score.setText(newscore);
            return R.drawable.d;
        }

        if(Id() == R.drawable.a){ 
            newscore = newscore+1;
        }

        if(Id() == R.drawable.b){ 
            newscore = newscore+10;
        }

        if(Id() == R.drawable.c){
            newscore = newscore+100;
        }

        if(Id() == R.drawable.d){ 
            newscore = newscore+1000;
        }


        }


    }
```

Comment: Add the line `newscore = newscore + [NUMBER]` in the respective `case` block before the `return` statement.

Comment: You are returning a number within the switch case, all the other code, starting with `if` are not reachable.
You need to rewrite the code

Comment: You should read up on the [return keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the switch statement in a method, this is how your Activity should look:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView score;
    public int newscore;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);    


       Random rand = new Random();
    int image = rand.nextInt(4);
    int newImage = getImageResourceId(image);

    if(newImage == R.drawable.a){ 
         newscore = newscore+1;
         score.setText(newscore);
    }

    if(newImage == R.drawable.b){ 
         newscore = newscore+10;
         score.setText(newscore);
     }

     if(newImage == R.drawable.c){
          newscore = newscore+100;
          score.setText(newscore);
     }

     if(newImage == R.drawable.d){ 
           newscore = newscore+1000;
           score.setText(newscore);
     }
}

public int getImageResourceId(int image) { 

switch (image) {
     case 0:
         return R.drawable.a;
     case 1: 
         return R.drawable.b;
     case 2:
         return R.drawable.c;
     case 3: 
         return R.drawable.d;
     default:
         return R.drawable.a;
    }
}

}
```

**Further Reading:**

1. [Writing your own Java Methods](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_methods.html)
2. [Returning a value from a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Comment: at the `publi int getDrawable()` I get an error `The return type is incompatible with Context.getDrawable(int)`

Comment: you can name it anything it doesn't have to be getDrawable(); i'll edit it to show you how the code should look fully.

Comment: Ah I see, I try it

Comment: check the edit, that is how your whole class should look

Comment: The answer seems right, but the suggested code can be optimized and reduced to a great extent.

Comment: @prerak this is only based around his current code, I could suggest improvements but then he wouldn't learn anything valuable from the current code he has written.

Comment: Is it not possible to call the if statements afterwards and keep the possibility to combine it with other conditions?

Comment: it is being called afterwards, you can call those if statements whenever you like aslong as they are after newImage = getImageResourceId(int image) otherwise newImage will be null.

Comment: please make sure you read the further reading to better understand the current code you have (that i have ammended for you) this will do everything you need it to do for now, thus answering the question.

Comment: I get an error for your code `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo:android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xa`?

Comment: because you haven't done all cases in the switch statement check the edit.

Comment: Can you tell me a thing anyway? Does `int getImageResourceId` return the number of the case or `R.drawable. .. `?

Comment: yeah it returns the id as an int, you can log it by writing Log.e("drawable", "value" + newImage); after newImage = getImageResourceId(image);

Comment: So if it's `case 0:` it returns a 0 as well?, or what do you mean?

Comment: if it's case 0 it'll return drawable a

Answer (score 0):

You will do `switch` and always return, because `switch-case` with `default case` always returns so:

```
if(Id() == R.drawable.a){ 
        newscore = newscore+1;
    }

    if(Id() == R.drawable.b){ 
        newscore = newscore+10;
    }

    if(Id() == R.drawable.c){
        newscore = newscore+100;
    }

    if(Id() == R.drawable.d){ 
        newscore = newscore+1000;
    }
```

will never run.

Comment: Why won't it run?

Comment: Because no matter what path is taken through the `switch` block that you wrote, they all end in a `return` statement. That `return` statement transfers the code back to the original block that called the function, ending the evaluation of code within the `Id()` function. Anything that happens after a `return` statement can never be executed because it will never be reached no matter what happens. It isn't an inherent rule though, if you rewrote the code it could work. It is just that you miscoded the `switch` and it isn't going to do what you want the way it is currently written.